# Как использовать изображение в качестве символа списка?

Tags: java, .net, pdf, itext

Я знаю, что `SetListSymbol` (из библиотеки `ITextSharp`) использует `string` в качестве параметра, возможно ли вместо этого использовать изображение/иконку? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите пример [ListWithImageAsBullet](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/develop/samples/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/objects/ListWithImageAsBullet.java). В примере мы берем изображение лампочки и используем его в качестве маркера списка:

```js
Image image = Image.getInstance(IMG);
image.scaleAbsolute(12, 12);
image.setScaleToFitHeight(false);
List list = new List();
list.setListSymbol(new Chunk(Image.getInstance(image), 0, 0));
list.add("Hello World");
list.add("This is a list item with a lot of text. It will certainly take more than one line. This shows that the list item is indented and that the image is used as bullet.");
list.add("This is a test");
document.add(list);
```

Результат выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изображение в качестве маркера списка

Comment: не работающая ссылка у вас "ListWithImageAsBullet"